# ANDROID_ID changes once signing key changed, but does the signing key change by a system update?

Tags: java, android, mobile

At this [Android Developers link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#privacy-all) it is stated that

> The value of ANDROID_ID does not change even if **a system update causes the package signing key to change**.

Can a system update change an app's package signing key? And if so, how?

Comment: As the documentation for `ANDROID_ID` says: _"The value **may** change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes"_. So it can happen, and you shouldn't rely on it not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a system update could change a package's signing key is if that package is in the system image.  A normal app (that is, one downloaded from the app store that is not part of the system image) would not have its signing key changed.

That is to say: a system update, without a factory reset or a reinstall of the app, will not change the app's ANDROID_ID, and it won't change the signing key either, except *possibly* if that app is included with the system image.